# How to get a tiled map into Java

Tags: java, tiled

I've been trying to figure out how to put a map from tiled into my Java project, but my finds tell me to convert a tiled map to .xml and my version of tiled doesn't have that type available. The version I have is 0.17.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find links to Java libraries in the [documentation](http://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/reference/support-for-tmx-maps/#java), provided you are trying to read the TMX formt.

You can get it the [official Java Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapeditor/libtiled/0.17) from Maven [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapeditor/libtiled/0.17).

Comment: I need to use a library to use tiled maps in Java?

Comment: You don't need to use the library. But it is usually easier to only have to deal with the concepts, instead of also parsing the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TMX format. It is XML already. You can also export to JSON and use it as your map format

Comment: I didn't realize that.